# My Onclick handler returns false, but my form is still submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with a submit button, and a validator attached to it via onclick=.... When I click on the submit button, the validator is executed and returns false. Still, the form is submitted. How can this be?

To narrow the problem further, I even changed the code temporarily to:

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="cgi-bin/process_contact_form.rb">
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Abschicken" onclick="false && k_validate('de')" />
</form>
```

This would just return false and bypass my validator. Indeed, even in this version, the form gets submitted.

Note that I am aware that there are means to get a form submitted with bypassing the validator. I am here only interested in the "normal" case, i.e. when a user explicitly clicks the button.

I have tested this on Mac OSX 10.6.8, using the following browsers:

SeaMonkey 2.0.14
Safari 5.1.10
Chrome 36.0

JavaScript is, of course, enabled.

The test page with the aforementioned "false" shortcut can be seen here:

http://www.tsukaeru-doitsugo.de/testing.html

It has two buttons. The first button (labelled "Abschicken") is the one within the form. Its onclick handler returns false, but the form is still submitted.

Comment: This would be true with the OR operator (false || X always returns X). With AND, the RHS is not evaluated if the LHS is already false (because false&&X is always false, independent of the value of X).

Comment: Actually, I could equally well have just written onclick="false". It was just easier to edit in this way, because eventually, I plan of course to remove the 'false &&' and let my validator run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the return-statement:

```
<input type="submit" value="Abschicken" onclick="return k_validate('de')" />
```

Comment: … which means the onclick function returns `undefined` which will not prevent the default action.

Comment: I do need a return in the "onclick"????????? 'return' is only used inside a function, I thought. BTW, I followed the example here, which also doesn't use a return: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php

Comment: Just tested it. With "return", it works! Thanks so much.... And I just learned to not trust tutorials blindly ;-)